# How to write predicate for union join and inner queries?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicate

I have a sql statement and I have to convert it into predicate to pass into a method.

```
select * from applications
where IsSuspended = 0 
union
select * from Applications where
id not in 
(select ApplicationAssociationId from Applications where ApplicationAssociationId is not NULL )
and IsSuspended = 1
```

my method call is like this. I tried many other way but not get success. :(

```
var resultList = someinstance.GetAll(
                    app=> app.IsSuspended = false)
                    .Union(someinstance.GetAll(
                    xap=>!xap.Id.Contains((xap.ApplicationAssociationId !=null).select(xap.Id)))
                    ).ToList();
```

Table Containing Data

[image]


Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you need a union at all here. Isn't it just an "or" condition?

```
var query = applications.Where(
     x => !x.IsSuspended ||
          !applications.Any(y => x.Id == y.ApplicationAssociationId));
```

(There's no need to check for IsSuspended being true in the second case, as if it's false it'll already be included in the first case.)